# sum values and conditional statement, subquery for yes no string values

Tags: sql, subquery, amazon-redshift

I need choose a string value for several columns while also summing numeric columns from a table.

Dataset

| id | person | expense | revenue | records | public |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 12 | 1 | 2 | Yes | No |
| abc | 11 | 1 | 5 | No | Yes |
| abc | 10 | 50 | 75 | Yes |  |
| abc | 9 | 1000 | 20000 | No | No |
| bcd | 1 | 20 | 25 | No | No |
| cde | 5 | 0 | 0 | No |  |

Working Code

```
select id, sum(expense) as sum_expense, sum(revenue) as sum(revenue)
from database 
group by id
```

How do I add some type of conditional statement or subquery for the string value columns records and public, to select Yes from the array when (Yes, No or Null) values exists, No when (No or Null) values exist and Null if only null exists.

Expected Result

| id | expense | revenue | records | public |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1052 | 2082 | Yes | Yes |
| bcd | 20 | 25 | No | No |
| cde | 0 | 0 | No |  |

Comment: Do you really have `(null)` verbatim in your table, or is actually null.

Comment: With your sample data just max(records) works. That will be Yes when any Yes exists, otherwise No if a No exists, otherwise just Null. Of course that just hinges on coincidence because your precedence is already alphabetized.

Comment: missing so not a value of (null)

Comment: Ok. In that case, just modify as Error2646 mentions. Just add `max(records), max(public)` to your select statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by using conditional aggregation to select the appropriate string value for the 'records' and 'public' columns based on the values present in each group. Here's how you can modify your query to achieve this:

```sql
SELECT 
    id,
    SUM(expense) AS sum_expense,
    SUM(revenue) AS sum_revenue,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN records = 'Yes' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN records = 'No' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'No'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS records,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN public = 'Yes' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN public = 'No' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'No'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS public
FROM 
    database
GROUP BY 
    id;
```

Explanation:

- The `CASE` statements inside the `SELECT` clause are used for conditional logic to determine the value of the 'records' and 'public' columns.
- Within each `CASE` statement:

  - The `COUNT(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 END)` counts the occurrences of 'Yes' or 'No' values within each group.
  - If there are any 'Yes' values, 'Yes' is selected. If there are any 'No' values but no 'Yes' values, 'No' is selected. Otherwise, `NULL` is selected.
- The `SUM(expense)` and `SUM(revenue)` aggregate functions are used to calculate the sum of expenses and revenue for each 'id' group as before.

This query will give you the expected result with the appropriate string values for the 'records' and 'public' columns based on the conditions specified. Adjust the column and table names as needed based on your actual schema.